# How can I "cast" a pointer type in Go to match the type of the pointed-to value?

Tags: go

I have a slice that contains different variable types.  Some strings, integers, etc.  Is there any way for me to "cast" a pointer to one of these values from `*interface{}` to `*string` or `*int32` where appropriate.

Here is a toy program that demonstrates the issue: http://play.golang.org/p/J3zgrYyXPq

```
// Store a string in the slice
valSlice := make([]interface{}, 1)
var strVal string = "test"
valSlice[0] = strVal

// Create a pointer to that string
ptrToStr := &valSlice[0]

// Outputs "string vs *interface {}"
fmt.Printf("%T vs %T\n", valSlice[0], ptrToStr) 

// Attempt 1 (doesn't compile):
// ----------------------------
// How can I cast the pointer type to (*string), referencing the same
// memory location as strVal?
// This doesn't compile:
//var castPtr *string = &valSlice[0].(string)

// Attempt 2 (after assertion, doesn't point to the same memory location):
var sureType string = valSlice[0].(string)
var castPtr *string = &sureType
*castPtr = "UPDATED"
fmt.Println(valSlice[0]) // Outputs "test", not "UPDATED"
```

If I need to justify my desire to do this, here's the explanation.  The `database/sql` package looks at the pointer type when scanning values.  My code has already prepared a slice holding zero-valued variables of the correct types to match the resultset.

Because `Scan` requires pointers, I iterate over my slice and build a new slice of pointers to the variables in my original slice.  I then pass this slice of pointers into the `Scan`.  But because the act of creating a pointer as above results in an `*interface{}` pointer instead of one that matches the variable type, the `Scan` does not know the underlying datatype to convert the raw `[]byte` value to.

Answer (score 2):

1 You must know , when a var is assigned to a interface , what happend ?

```
str := "hello world"
var tmp interface{} = str
```

the complier will create a tempotary object , which has the same value with `str` ,and `tmp` is associated with it.  So  after that , all you do to `tmp` is not associated with `str`. But go doesn't allow you to change the tempotary object。 So you can't have  the dereference of the tempotary object in `interface` and you can't change it, that's why the errors exist. If you want more information about the implements of `interface`, read http://research.swtch.com/interfaces

2  If you want change the original object, pass the pointer to a interface

```
valSlice := make([]interface{}, 1)
var strVal string = "test"
valSlice[0] = &strVal //pass a pointer to a interafce
var castPtr *string = valSlice[0].(*string) // get the pointer
*castPtr = "UPDATED"//change the string strVal
fmt.Println(strVal) // Outputs "UPDATE"
```